# Asking the same question in multiple fora, is it spamming?

Tags: support

Is asking the same question as in math.SE in sci.math, forums, etc. considered spamming?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable to ask a question on Stack Exchange and also on other forums outside the SE network. Barring issues of copyright, we are largely agnostic to what exists elsewhere in terms of our own quality standards. So, as long as the question is up to our quality standards, it is okay to post here.

There's certainly no requirement to do so, but I think it's usually a good idea to include links between wherever you post the same question. There's probably some overlap between such forums, so that can help avoid duplicated effort. It also helps M.SE users see if there's an answer or helpful discussion elsewhere (which can help them provide an answer here) or users of other forums see that there's an M.SE question, and perhaps write an answer here.

It's also worth noting that we have a narrow definition of spam: spam is limited to posts that promote a product rather than ask/answer a mathematical question. However, I assume that intent of the question was more about whether this is good form than whether it's "spam."

Comment: Some of the reasons against multiple posts are still valid, even if they are outside SE.  There could be unnecessary duplication of effort if those answering in one forum do not know about answers in another forum.  So you would be taking up efforts that could have been devoted to answering other, unique, questions.